# How is n-gram different from k-mer?

Tags: strings, string-metrics, substrings, subsequences, bioinformatics

How is n-gram different from k-mer? Both seem to be (n or k) length substrings of a larger string. Are these just terms common with different practitioners? viz. Computer Scientists and Bioinformaticians?

Comment: The wiki for "n-gram" states at the top: "For applications in computational genomics, see k-mer." So yes, I believe they're just in different domains.

Comment: Oh... Thanks.. I missed the fine print :-)

Comment: And to add - "k-shingle" also means the same thing. :-O. NLP folks i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they mean the same thing.  A n-gram is a sequence of n consecutive things (words, letters, whatever).  A k-mer is a sequence of k consecutive things (DNA basepairs).  The phrase k-mer is more common in computational genomics.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer for definitions.